# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am getting the following error while doing an INSERT into another table (`ApplicationTasks`) with this FK:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ApplicationTasks_Application__ApplicationId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "Status", table "dbo.Application", column
>   'ApplicationId'.

This occurs all the time but we still have records being inserted into the `ApplicationTasks` table. The inserts could be multiple times per second. I didn't think there would be any kind of blocking\locking that would cause this. The `ApplicationId` that it references already exists in the `Application` table.

Any thoughts that would direct me to a fix for this?

Edited: I can't add pictures yet to my post, so here is the best I can do for query\data:

Application Table:

```
SELECT [ApplicationId]
  ,[ApplicationName]
  FROM [Status].[dbo].[Application]
  WHERE ApplicationId = 498
```

Result:

```
ApplicationId   ApplicationName

498             Tst ESB PowerEnterprise.PO.MG
```

ApplicationTasks Table:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [TaskId]
  ,[Task]
  ,[ApplicationId]
  ,[RunTime]
  FROM [Status].[dbo].[ApplicationTasks]
  WHERE ApplicationId = 498
```

Result:

```
TaskId      Task        ApplicationId   RunTime
769893930   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 07:45:21.080
769894958   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 08:30:10.857
769895327   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 08:45:15.517
769895328   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 08:45:16.063
769896677   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 09:45:13.427
769896678   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 09:45:13.473
769897019   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 10:00:17.103
769897020   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 10:00:17.743
769897356   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 10:15:19.423
769897703   Dummy Task  498             2016-04-25 10:30:13.023
```

As you can see, the ApplicationId of 498 is in the Application table and there are records that have been INSERTed into the ApplcationTasks table for this ApplicationId.  But it still throws this error.  Could it be because it runs so frequently?

Edited again:

FK on ApplicationTasks

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationTasks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationTasks_Application__ApplicationId] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([ApplicationId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationTasks] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationTasks_Application__ApplicationId]
GO
```

Stored Proc being called by the code:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_applicationtasks_insert](
@applicationkey INT,
  @task VARCHAR(40),
  @userid VARCHAR(40),
  @runtime DATETIME,
  @taskstatus VARCHAR(20),
  @detail VARCHAR(500),
  @applicationstate VARCHAR(20),
  @host VARCHAR(40) 
)
AS

BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [applicationtasks]
(
  [ApplicationId],
  [Task], 
  [UserId],
  [RunTime], 
  [Status], 
  [Detail],
  [ApplicationState], 
  [Host]
) VALUES (
  @applicationkey,
  @task,
  @userid,
  @runtime,
  @taskstatus,
  @detail,
  @applicationstate,
  @host    
)
  COMMIT TRANSACTION

  RETURN @@Identity
END
```

Example statement that fails ***periodically***:

```
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_applicationtasks_insert] 
   @applicationkey = 498
  ,@task = "Dummy Task" 
  ,@userid = ''
  ,@runtime = getdate()
  ,@taskstatus = ''
  ,@detail = ''
  ,@applicationstate = ''
  ,@host = 'SERVERNAME'
```

Comment: You tried to insert a child record for which no parent record existed. That's basically it. But since you've provided no useful details (like sample query/data), that's just a guess.

Comment: I edited the post with more info to hopefully help.

Comment: Better. But table definitions of the relevant fields and FKs would be very useful too.

Comment: The data that exists in the tables by definition isn't the data rejected because it doesn't satisfy the constraint - show us what are you trying to add not what succeded

Comment: Edited it again.  Thanks all for the help and direction!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is trying to insert a non-existent applicationid in the ApplicationTasks table.

Example:

supposing your dbo.Application table has the following data:

```
applicationid - description - data
  1       -    test         - 09192016 
  2       -    test2        - 09192016
  3       -    test3        - 09192016
```

If you try to insert and applicationid on 4 or more in the ApplicationTasks table, you'll get this errors, because you broke the relationship.

Comment: That's the thing though, the applicationid that I'm trying to insert into ApplicationTasks DOES exist in the Application table.  That's the confusing part.

Comment: can you post more info about your db? the details of that relationship, the data being inserted and etc?